# get all properties of a feature

Tags: google-earth-engine, features

I want to get the `properties` of a `feature`. How can I do that?
In the example below we can get one of the properties out like so `feature.get('species')`. How can we get all of them at once?
This is a failure `feature.get('properties')`

It works for `geometry` like `feature.geometry()` but not for `properties`.

```
// Make a feature and set some properties.
var feature = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-122.22599, 37.17605]))
  .set('genus', 'Sequoia').set('species', 'sempervirens');

// Get a property from the feature.
print(feature.get('species'));

print(feature.get('properties'));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
//dictionary of property names and values
print(feature.toDictionary())

//or list of either property names or values
print(feature.toDictionary().keys())
print(feature.toDictionary().values())
```

Comment: `print(feature.toDictionary(feature.propertyNames()))` if you also want the system properties